# How & where can I setup servers for a learning development project?

Tags: usergroups

Backgroud:
I am a board member of the [Fox Valley .Net User Group](http://fvnug.org). We are starting a Special Interest Group to do a software project from start to finish. We want to focus on having senior .Net members help junior .Net members learn tools and technologies. We want to learn how to use or better use the following software:

1. Team Foundation Server 2008 - Very Important to Learn
2. MS Build - Very Important to Learn
3. Visual Studio Team Systems 2008 - Very Important to Learn
4. SQL Server 2008 - Somewhat Important to Learn

My Plan:
Create different virtual machines for TFS 2008, Build Server, SQL Server 2008.

This project is planned to assist all who participate to learn the tools and practices needed to stay atop the .Net development world. We find that lots of members of the user group are still using VB 6, .Net 1.1, SQL 2000, non agile practices and other legacy things in there daily job.

My Questions:

1. Where can I host these VMs so everyone has access and keep the cost low or zero?
2. If hosting is not possible, does CodePlex offer TFS access? Does it offer agile? Work Items? Reports?
3. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks for the help and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best way is to use CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the available virtual labs Hosted by Microsoft?
That would eliminate your responsibility for hosting anything.  You would also not have to be concerned about any licensing issues with the software that is installed on the Virtual Images.

There are a number of labs for [Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/aa740411.aspx) on the Microsoft site.

You can also go to the root [Virtual Labs Site](http://www.microsoft.com/events/vlabs/default.mspx) where there is a complete listing of available labs.  Ths way the responsibilty for hosting is not yours, Microsoft has taken care of it.

Also don't forget to look at [Microsoft Learning](http://learning.microsoft.com/Manager/Catalog.aspx), there are frequently free offerings for newer technologies that give someone a basic overview, you won't be an expert but it will give you a basic understanding.  There are also more indepth offerings but they are usually pay for access.

Good luck and hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now that sounds like an interesting project.

1) Perhaps one of the local hosting companies will sponsor a box to host the VMs, or ask one of the ISVs for a host in the DMZ. It is hard work to rein in a sponsor but it will also give you a lot of contacts in the industry.

2) I doubt Codeplex will be a solution for this project as it is very TFS-centric.

3) Have you asked the local Microsoft office? The office here in Copenhagen, Denmark have often helped a lot, even with issues that they knew nothing about but they have always found just the right guy.